# this is not defined error in javascript class constructor?

Tags: javascript, class

I can't get my name parameter in my Employee class ! I don't know why I getting error like **`this is not undefined`** ! `this` is for current object right! I don't how to output my name parameter?

```
class Person {
    constructor(n, a) {
        var p = this;
        p.n = n;
        p.a = a;
        p.total = 0;
        p.a.map(x => p.total += parseInt(x)); //get total salary     
    }
    firstName() {
        return this.n = "Min Min ";
    }
    displayMsg() {
        return " and My yearly income is " + this.total;
    }
}

class Employee extends Person {
    constructor(name, age) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    lastName() {
        return this.name;
    }
    Show() {
        return "My name is " + super.firstName() + this.lastName() + super.displayMsg();
    }
}
emp = new Employee("David", [123, 456, 754]);
console.log(emp.Show());
```

*Actual Output*

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: this is not defined
```

*Expected Output*

```
My name is Min Min David  and My yearly income is 1333
```

Comment: The actual error I get in Firefox 48.0a2 is `ReferenceError: |this| used uninitialized in Employee class constructor`.

Comment: I have seen that duplicate question's answer and tested ! But get error in `.map` function.

Comment: It's ok now, under answer solved my question ! I just point out that duplicate question's answer doesn't solve my OP.

Comment: I think the difference is `super()` and `super(name,age)` ! If I just used `super()`, It is getting *Cannot read property 'map' of undefined* error . Using `super(name,age)` is worked.

Comment: As I thought… there’s a comment under that answer now.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to **call the `super()` constructor** first before you can continue instantiating your class:

```
class Employee extends Person {
    constructor(name, age) {
        super(name, age);
        this.name = name;
    }

    ...
}
```

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/yiditox/edit?js,console)